# Evaluating $\int_2^4\frac{\arctan x}{\log x}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I've been trying to improve my integration techniques, and I came up with the following integral which I thought I could solve with Feynman Integration
$$I=\int_2^4\frac{\arctan x}{\log x}dx$$
Here's what I've tried so far:
$$F(a)=\int_2^4\frac{\arctan(x^a)}{\log x}dx$$
$$F'(a)=\int_2^4\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\frac{\arctan(x^a)}{\log x}dx$$
$$F'(a)=\int_2^4\frac{x^a}{x^{2a}+1}dx$$
$x=\tan u$: $$F'(a)=\int_{\arctan2}^{\arctan4}\frac{\tan^au\sec^2u}{\tan^{2a}u+1}du$$
$$F'(a)=\int_{\arctan2}^{\arctan4}\frac{\frac{\sin^au}{\cos^{a+2}u}}{\frac{\sin^{2a}u}{\cos^{2a}u}+1}du$$
$$F'(a)=\int_{\arctan2}^{\arctan4}\frac{\sin^au\cos^{2a}u}{\cos^{a+2}u(\sin^{2a}u+\cos^{2a}u)}du$$
$$F'(a)=\int_{\arctan2}^{\arctan4}\frac{\sin^au\cos^{a-2}u}{\sin^{2a}u+\cos^{2a}u}du$$
Which I don't know how to handle. How do I integrate this? Thanks.

Comment: @piquito I did not expect that it was (Feynman integration is not elementary). I would be fine with expressing the integral in terms of a special function or series

Comment: @clathratus Normally, when you concoct an arbitrary function of natural logs and arctangents together, you (99% of the time) won't get an elementary solution or even a closed form solution. Especially considering the arbitrary limits two and four, I highly doubt a closed form exists. In that case, I think the best you can do is approximate your value. Of course, you're allowed to prove me wrong. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NOTE: The following is a partial but incomplete answer.

---

Consider 
$$F(a) = \int_2^4 \frac{\arctan(x)}{\ln(x)}x^a\,dx.$$
Then 
$$\frac{d}{da}F(a) = \int_2^4 \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \frac{\arctan(x)}{\ln(x)}x^a\,dx = \int_2^4 \arctan(x) x^{a}\,dx .$$
Note that 
$$\int \arctan(x) x^{a}\,dx = \frac{\arctan(x) x^{a+1}}{a+1} - \frac{1}{a+1}\int \frac{x^{a+1}}{1+x^2}\,dx.$$
From [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(x%5E(a%2B1%7D)%2F(1%2Bx%5E2)+from+2+to+4), we have 
$$\int \frac{x^{a+1}}{1+x^2}\,dx = \frac{1}{2} i^{-a} \left( B(-4; \frac{a}{2}+1,0) - B(-16; \frac{a}{2}+1,0) \right)$$
where $B(z;a,b)$ is the [incomplete Beta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html).
Then we have 
$$\frac{d}{da}F(a) = \frac{\arctan(4)4^{a+1} - \arctan(2)2^{a+1}}{a+1} - \frac{i^{-a}}{2(a+1)}\left( B(-4; \frac{a}{2}+1,0) - B(-16; \frac{a}{2}+1,0) \right).$$

Comment: Oh this is perfect! I should've known the incomplete beta function was going to show up somewhere

Comment: @clathratus However I am not able to calculate $F(a).$ My answer gives $F'(a).$

Comment: I know. But I'll keep this answer accepted until a more complete one comes along